# spreadsheet like ui grid for 50000 and above data sets

Tags: excel-formula, open-source, spreadsheet, slickgrid, handsontable

i am working on a project where i need to have a similar google spreadsheet like ui and same functionality which google spreadsheet have including formulas formatting , and most importantly it should handle large data sets of rows approx 
50000 rows.
**i have used handsontable library for spreadsheet but it dont contain functionbar and its taking too much time to load large data sets.**
**i researched about other open source spreadsheet grid, 
i found slickgrid and kendo ui** , please suggest me which one should i use for **large data sets** which does not affect on performance and should have **same ui like google spreadsheet and formula bar.**

Answer (score 1):

SlickGrid is great at displaying large datasets due to its virtual scrolling. However, spreadsheets are not its main purpose and you might find it a lot of work to do what you are describing. Slickgrid is more of a toolkit than anything - the foundations are great, and you can build a solid structure on top. But it's not going to give you what you want out of the box.

Ag-Grid is a another grid that is the only grid I've seen that is similar in design to SlickGrid, you might want to check it out - the basic version is free, for the more advanced features you need the paid version. In general, there's a large gap between grids that are good at display (there's a zillion of them), and ones that offer good editing features. That's generally the dividing line.

Note that what you are describing is something that companies have built whole businesses on - it's not going to be quick or easy no matter which way you go.

Comment: can i include formulas in SlickGrid

Comment: Slickgrid doesn't understand formulas out of the box. You'd have to build that functionality. Check out: www.ethercalc.net. Or google 'online spreadsheet open source'

Comment: ag-grid is free to use, only a few functionalities are paid which comes in the enterprise edition.